Why is $v\left( O(\|x\|^2) \right) = 0$ (where $v$ is a derivation on $T_0 \Bbb R^n$)?
A rather very basic question which I am unable to answer for myself. I'm trying to recall why the $\{ \partial/\partial x_j\}$ form a basis for the tangent space.
Basically, let's say we have an $\Bbb R$-linear operator $v$ on smooth maps such that $v$ satisfies the Leibniz rule, i.e. $v(fg) = f(0)v(g) + g(0)v(f)$. Suppose that $f = O(\|x\|^2)$. Why does it follow that $v(f) = 0$?
It would follow easily if $f$ is factorable as $hg$ where $h = O(\|x\|)$ and $g = O(\|x\|)$ are smooth, because one then just applies the Leibniz rule to get $v(f) = v(hg) = h(0)v(g) + g(0)v(h) = 0$. However, I'm not sure how exactly this can be done.
Another idea I had was to look at the Taylor expansion. If we are looking at finitely many terms, then yes it is clear that the result will be $0$. However, when we are considering infinitely many terms, there are convergence issues..
Maybe I am missing something very obvious, but yeah I'd appreciate any insight.

By hypothesis, $f(x)/||x||^2$ is bounded. What about $f(x)/||x||$?

@CaptainLama but is $f(x)/|x|$ smooth? (supposing we extend it to $0$ by defining it to be $0$ there). I can see why it is differentiable once - but more than once.. I'm not sure. Even in the case $n=1$, a map like this isn't generally $C^k$ for $k \ge 2$. No?

You need a stronger version of Taylor. Show that if $f$ is smooth, then there are smooth functions $g_i$ so that $$f(x)-f(0)=\sum x_ig_i(x),$$ and $g_i(0) = \partial f/\partial x_i(0)$.

I see, aka Hadamard's lemma. This makes it immediate. Thanks!
